# generic AST builder

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree

The Eclipse org.eclipse.jdt.astview does a great job in giving abstract syntax trees ... but its tailored towards Java ... is there some open source package available that does the same thing for other popular languages? May be some module of some IDE that I can extract?

Comment: Is open source your goal, or is ability to handle lots of languages well?

Comment: while "ability to handle lots of languages well" is definitely the goal, open source softwares are by default my _means_ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).   Open Source.  Has a lot of grammmars for various languages, including Java.   Builds ASTs and lets you manipulate them.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: Thanks for the answer, I'm looking into it. Right now I am using Pygments to automatically guess language type and extract tokens and token types from a source tree ... and its doing pretty well for that part.

Comment: @Tathagata: what is it you want to do?  Process multiple languages at the same time? For what purpose?

Comment: @Ira Baxter: Before I go any further, let me tell you what an honor it is for me to have you commenting on my question. :) I was blown away by your Google Tech talk and have heard about your seminal work on DMS from my advisor. My goal is precisely http://bit.ly/hiubZn, for which the source code analyzer should ideally be language agnostic.

Comment: @Tathagata: Thanks for the compliment.  Your advisor is ...?  So your goal is to prevent data loss by doing something to code?  (Based on most of the software engineering studies done over the years, most code is encrypted by specialists known as "programmers" to be completely opaque to humans and especially to other specialists :-}

Comment: @Ira Baxter:My advisor is http://www.cs.uic.edu/~drmark/. Haha ... yeah, I do agree with you on the "encryption". Whenever I checkout some code to read, the layers of folder structure each hiding in its womb a concoction of n different languages (rule of thumb n>=3, Java,XML,sh ..) make me numb at the first hit. Obfuscation(however inadvertent that may be) does has its upshots for security by obscurity... maintenance guys should probably disagree to that.